# Set Vector Drawable in ImageView cause app crash in old SDK

Tags: android, vector, crash, drawable, android-appcompat

I used Vector Drawable in image src like this:

```
 <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/isSold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_soldout_24px"
                tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
```

I also added these to manifest:

```
defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary=true
    }
```

and I used     `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'`

but my app crashes in old sdk with message of `Error inflating class ImageView`

Comment: and does it still crash if you remove `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_soldout_24px"`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead of ImageView:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/isSold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_soldout_24px"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
```

Comment: you dont need to use "AppCompat*" views as they are automagically injected when using appcompat library

Comment: thnx . . .Enjoy coding :)

Comment: @pskink . how I can use ImageView that act like support imageView as long as I added the support library to Gradle?

Comment: @Kenji just use <ImageView> tag, start your activity and execute command `adb shell dumpsys activity top`

Comment: Thanks Rohit, it helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Use normal `<ImageView>`, **IF** the top-level activity/dialog is provided by `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`.

You should only need to manually use `AppCompatImageView` when writing custom views.

This is from docs.